# how to Create Group under Facebook APP in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group, facebook-game-groups

```
//App Token string AccessToken = "41389678736"; 

  try {

        var fb = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
        dynamic fbInfo = fb.Post("/v2.2/" + "9192461854" + "/groups", new
        {
            name = "Create APP Group one",
            description = "Create APP Group one",
            admin = "14563132194",
        });

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
```

[image]

Comment: i am not able to create Group under APP using Facebook API.i am trying create Group Using POST Request.

Comment: i followed below article javascript SDK panel. but i need to create Group using C#.    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/game-groups/v2.1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a global Facebook Group via the Graph API. See the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group

If you want to creaete an app group, you could do this via

```
POST /v2.4/{app-id}/groups
```

As stated in the docs, you need an App Access Token for that

> An app access token is required to create groups belonging to that app.

You seem to use an invalid Access Token. Try one in the form `app_id|app_secret`

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/app/groups#publish
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

Comment: Thanks for response, i am trying to create group under Facebook Game APP.

Comment: Ok, this is something different. You should explicitly state that in your question! Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks ,How i will call "POST /v2.4/{app-id}/groups HTTP/1.1" in C#.i have attached screenshot of my code of my process.

Comment: The request itself works, otherwise you wouldn't receive an error message. You need to pass a correct access token, as I wrote

Comment: can you share any sample process. // this is my sample code.    //string AccessToken = "4213883333062916|NfCX-g3UexZYc9F_xhyrSmtStsE";
        try
        {


            var fb = new FacebookClient(AccessToken1);
            dynamic fbInfo = fb.Post("/v2.4/" + "421344388062916" + "/groups", new
            {
                name = "Demo From from CSharp",
                description = "Demo From from CSharp Demo",
                admin = "100014493132194",
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }